# Way to update UI after database change has occured

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-loader

I'm developing an app based on [Google IO presentation](https://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-developing-RESTful-android-apps.pdf) architecture using the first approach. Basically I have a `Service`, `ContentProvider` backed by `SQLite` DB and I also use `Loader`s.

I need a way to update UI when changes to my database occur. For instance a user might want to add an item into his basket. After I insert the item id into the basket table I want to update the UI. What approach should I use? I've seen very little information on `ContentObserver` so far. Is it the way to go?

Comment: the item in the basket is combined with an *insert* operation in the database?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean but basically after the http request is completed I update corresponding row in the database table, which state should somehow be mirrored by the UI. My problem is that I can't  seem to find a way to tell UI to update after DB data has been changed.

Comment: did you call notifyChange after you updated the row?

Comment: is your sql query located in the adapter?or are you feeding only the arraylist to the adapter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the `query` method of your `ContentProvider` attach a listener to the returned cursor:

```
 Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(dbConnection, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
 cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
```

Then in your `insert`/`update`/`delete` methods use code like this:

```
 final long objectId = dbConnection.insertOrThrow(ObjectTable.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
 final Uri newObjectUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(OBJECT_CONTENT_URI, objectId );
 getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(newObjectUri , null);
```

Your `CursorLoader` will be notified and the `OnLoadFinished(Loader, Cursor)` will be called again.

If you're not using a `Loader`, the **`ContentObserver`** is the way to go, with a few lines of code you are notified on db changes (but you will need to requery manually).

```
  private ContentObserver objectObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        restartObjectLoader();
    }
};
```

Remember to call in `onResume()`:

```
 getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ObjectProvider.OBJECT_CONTENT_URI, false, objectObserver);
```

and in `onPause()`:

```
 getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(objectObserver);
```

**Update: UI Changes**
This is a larger topic because it depends on the `Adapter` you use to fill the `ListView` or `RecyclerView`.

**CursorAdapter**
In `onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Cursor data)`

```
 mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
```

**ArrayAdapter**
In `onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Cursor data)`

```
 Object[] objects = transformCursorToArray(data); //you need to write this method
 mAdapter.setObjects(objects); //You need to wrie this method in your implementation on the adapter
 mAdapter.notifyDataSetChange();
```

**RecyclerView.Adapter**
In `onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Cursor data)`

```
 Object[] objects = transformCursorToArray(data); //you need to write this method
 //Here you have more mAdapter.notify....()
```

Read [from here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) for different way to notify the `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a list, you can fill adapter again and set it to your list. Or try to inform data set change.